# uwsgi закрывает соединение без отправки ответа

Tags: python, uwsgi

Развернуто django приложение на сервере uwsgi в контейнере.
Если сделать два GET запроса; подождать некоторое время, затем PUT, затем ещё два GET, то все проходит нормально;
Если сделать два GET запроса; затем (без задержки) PUT, затем ещё два GET запроса, то сервер uwsgi закрывает соединение без ответа (unexpected end of file from server executing PUT http://..)

Вывод tcpdump показывает, что сервер не отвечает, т.е. запрос отклоняется сервером uwsgi.

Конфиг файл uwsgi:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /app
wsgi-file = app/wsgi.py
master = True
pidfile = /tmp/project-master.pid
http = 0.0.0.0:8080
processes = 10
threads = 10

env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.test

enable-threads = true

logger = internalservererror file:/src/errors.log
log-route = internalservererror (HTTP/1.\d 500)
req-logger = file/src/uwsgi_error1.log
threaded-logger = file/src/uwsgi_error2.log

logger-req = stdio
log-req-encoder = json {"timestamp":"${strftime:%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S.666Z}","source":"req", "msg":"${msg}"}

log-format = %(method) %(uri) | %(status) | %(secs)}
log-req-encoder = nl
```

В логах не вижу причины, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, Спасибо

Comment: угадываю вероятную причину, возможно нет ни какой закономерности в том как делать запросы. проблема в их одновременном количестве и том что приложение крешится из за того что один запрос мешает другому или просто всплывает ошибка в приложении. было бы хорошо прикрипить логи чтобы удостоверится и возможно повысить уровень логирования до дебага в джанге. А почему `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.test` стоит? это тесты запускаются?

Comment: Логи добавил ,ничего нет, проблема в том, что uwsgi, вероятно, не поддерживает `Connection: Keep-Alive`. Изначально было следующее:
если сделать два GET; подождать некоторое время, затем PUT, затем ещё два GET, то всё работает нормально;
если между запросами не делать задержки (или сделать менее 3 сек), то упадет ошибка. По uwsgi не нашел понятного мне описания работы с keey-alive, нашёл по Apache: он может держать один tcp запрос на обработку нескольких http в течение 5 сек.
По-хорошему настроить бы uwsgi на работу с keep-alive, но решили просто забить и не использовать коннекшион повторно